# Obvious question about a comb set

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Define the set $A = \{ (x,0) : 0 \leq x \leq 1 \} $ and $B_n = \left\{\left( \frac{1}{n},y\right) : n \in \mathbb{N}, 0 \leq y \leq 1 \right\} $

Then, does it follow that $A \cup B_n$ is path-connected?

It seems obvious, but how can I verify it? Thanks.

Comment: An idea: any point on $\;A\;$ can be connected with any point of the form $\;\left(\frac1n,0\right)\;$ , and *also* can any point on $\;B_n\;$ , for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ and every $B_n$ are convex sets, so they are path connected. Since $B_n\cap A\ne\emptyset$, the set $B_n\cup A$ is path connected for every $n$. Finally, $A\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}B_n=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A\cup B_n$ is path connected since $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A\cup B_n =A\ne\emptyset$ and the union of path connected sets is path connected if their intersection is not empty.